# ST-LINK v2 to STM32F401CC connection issue

Tags: stm32, st-link

I was working in small projects on eclipse IDE with the OCD of the MCU and it was working perfectly, till I made configurations on some pins `PIN8` to `PIN15` of `PORTA` and the MCU couldn't connect the PC again, it was just a simple program with configurations of `PORTA` as `OUTPUT`.

I tried STM32 ST-Link utility and gave me error ***Can not connect to target! Please select "Connect Under Reset" mode from Target->Settings menu and try again. If you're trying to connect to a low frequency application , please select a lower SWD Frequency mode from Target->Settings menu.***

I'm sure about the hardware connections between ST-LINK v2 and the STM32F401CC and I tried many projects before with no problems.[image]

Is there any way to solve this problem by erasing the Flash Memory manually or something else ?[image]

***Update:***
This is the new connection for the case of connecting them under reset mode[image]

Comment: So did you do as the program told you to do and connect under reset? And you have the reset connected between ST-Link and target board? Did you try the DFU via USB when booting to factory bootloader via BOOT0 and reset?

Comment: @Justme Here is some solutions that I tried,

1- when I did as the program says I got ***Can not connect to target!
                  If you're trying to connect to an STM32W1xx device, please select Normal or HotPlug mode from Target->Settings menu.
                  If you're trying to connect to a low frequency application , please select a lower SWD Frequency mode from Target->Settings menu.
***
so I return it to the normal mode again

Comment: Yes but what wires connect between ST-Link and your target board? Unless there is a reset wire, you can't connect under reset.

Comment: 2- I didn't connect the `R` Pin to the ST-Link, when I did it didn't give any result tho.

3- The last thing I did, I connected the `R` pin to the 3.3v pin so that `NRST` button be useful, then I did this (Hold `BOOT0` then press `NRST` then release `NRST` then release `BOOT0`) I read previously that these steps gets me in ***boot mode*** it gave another behavior but didn't work for burning or connect the MCU.

Comment: This is where I got the **boot mode** information [link](https://mischianti.org/2022/07/02/black-pill-stm32f4-pinout-specs-and-arduino-ide-configuration-4/)

Comment: You are mixing two things. And what do you mean by R pin? Don't connect NRST pin to 3.3V. Either connect NRST to ST-Link so it can connect under reset, or, connect via USB directly by using BOOT0.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity the R pin is the one as shown on the figure pin number 7 **RST**, it was connected to the 3.3v as I told u, but I changed the connection the **RST** pin on the MCU connected to the **RST** pin on the ST-Link this shown in the hardware connection picture I posted in the question and configured the program to **connect under reset** 

and I got this error 18:12:40 : STLink USB communication error.

Comment: The picture you posted in your question shows the 'R' (RST) pin connected to 3V3 on the board, not to the ST-Link. Show us how you connected it to the ST-Link.

Comment: @brhans thanks for your concern, I uploaded the picture for you but it wasn't the connection it made it works, it was the first one but with the method that Codo told me

Comment: Also very important : **that is not a genuine ST-Link, it is a clone with no guarantees if it works like an original.** My comments were based on assumption that a genuine ST-Link V2 was used.

Comment: The easiest way in my oppinion is to disconnect board from USB power and also disconect debugger (for prevent backpowering). On unpowered board press and hold reset button, then connect board to power but do not release the reset button. Then using second hand attach debugger wires, run STM32CubeProgrammer, connect to target and erase the target. Then you can power cycle board again, but you do not need to hold reset button anymore.

Comment: @Misaz Thanks for your concern, I did something like what you said but I pressed BOOT0 instead and it worked.

Comment: BOOT button work similarly, but instead of erasing chip under reset you erase when it si running bootloader code. In some rare cases method with BOOT pin do not work and reset is more reliable, but in most cases both should work well.

Answer (score 2):

By configuring pins PA13 and PA14, your firmware disables the debugging port when the MCU starts as the debugging port uses those pins.

In order to gain access to again, you have to prevent your firmware from starting. There are several options:

- Unplug your board. Then press the *BOOT0* button on the board while you reconnect it. Then upload a fixed firmware. By pressing this button, the built-in bootloader firmware is started instead of your custom firmware.
- Press the *Reset* button on your board and then start the upload of the fixed firmware. Immediately release the button when when OCD tries to connect to the board. This is a bit tricky to get right timing-wise. Pressing the release button prevents the MCU from starting any firmware at all.
- Instead of connecting the board using the ST-LINK v2, connect it using USB. When you connect it, press the *BOOT0* button. The MCU then boots the built-in bootloader firmware and goes into DFU mode as it detects a USB connection. Now you can use the DFU protocol to erase the flash memory:

```
dfu-util -a 0 -s 0x08000000:mass-erase:force:leave
```

Comment: I'm very thankful to you, 
I tried the first option then the MCU connected to the ST-Link utility program, then I did the full chip erase option and it worked !
thank you for your concern

Answer (score 0):

I did hold the BOOT0 button with the **connect under reset** mode configured in the ST-Link utility program and clicked on **full chip erase** option and it worked.

The problem was because of configuring Pins that I shouldn't have configure like <<PIN3 & PIN4 for PORTB and PIN13, PIN14 & PIN15 on PORTA>> that affect the connection between the MCU and the PC through the OCD or the ST-Link utility.